# SleekXMPP automatically accept all chat room invites

Tags: python, xmpp

I want to use SleekXMPP and automatically accept all chat room invites that are sent to me. I know that the xep_0045 plugin can detect when I receive an invite, as I am notified in the debugger. I am still pretty new to Python and any help would be appreciated.

So far, I've found a function called `handle_groupchat_invite` in the xep_0045 plugin. Specifically, this code:

```
def plugin_init(self):
        #...
        self.xmpp.registerHandler(Callback('MUCInvite', MatchXMLMask("<message xmlns='%s'><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'><invite></invite></x></message>" % self.xmpp.default_ns), self.handle_groupchat_invite))

#...

def handle_groupchat_invite(self, inv):
        """ Handle an invite into a muc.
        """
        logging.debug("MUC invite to %s from %s: %s", inv['from'], inv["from"], inv)
        if inv['from'].bare not in self.rooms.keys():
            self.xmpp.event("groupchat_invite", inv)
```

So I see this method at work as I see the "MUC invite to..." message in the Terminal log. From there, I would expect that I need to use `self.plugin['xep_0045'].joinMUC()` to join the chat room's URL (given by `inv["from"]`). However, I am not exactly sure where I should call this code in my script.

Thanks again for the help.

**Update:** I've also tried using `add_event_handler` in the `__init__` function. Specifically my code is:

```
def __init__(self, jid, password, room, nick):
    sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP.__init__(self, jid, password)

    self.room = room
    self.nick = nick

    # The session_start event will be triggered when
    # the bot establishes its connection with the server
    # and the XML streams are ready for use. We want to
    # listen for this event so that we we can initialize
    # our roster.
    self.add_event_handler("session_start", self.start)

    # The groupchat_message event is triggered whenever a message
    # stanza is received from any chat room. If you also also
    # register a handler for the 'message' event, MUC messages
    # will be processed by both handlers.
    self.add_event_handler("groupchat_message", self.muc_message)

    # The groupchat_presence event is triggered whenever a
    # presence stanza is received from any chat room, including
    # any presences you send yourself. To limit event handling
    # to a single room, use the events muc::room@server::presence,
    # muc::room@server::got_online, or muc::room@server::got_offline.
    self.add_event_handler("muc::%s::got_online" % self.room,
                           self.muc_online)

    self.add_event_hander("groupchat_invite", self.sent_invite)
```

From there, I created the `sent_invite` function, code is here:

```
def sent_invite(self, inv):
    self.plugin['xep_0045'].joinMUC(inv["from"], self.nick, wait=True)
```

However, I get the following error when I do this:

> File "muc.py", line 66, in **init**
>       self.add_event_hander("groupchat_invite", self.sent_invite) AttributeError: 'MUCBot' object has no attribute 'add_event_hander'

Yet in the xep_0045 plugin I see this code: `self.xmpp.event("groupchat_invite", inv)`. According to the Event Handlers SleekXMPP [wiki page](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/wiki/Event-Handlers),

> Stream events arise whenever particular stanzas are received from the XML stream. Triggered events are created whenever **xmpp.event(name, data)** is called (where xmpp is a SleekXMPP object).

Can someone please explain why I am getting the error? I've also tried using

```
self.add_event_hander("muc::groupchat_invite", self.sent_invite)
```

but also without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded SleekXMPP from git and add `groupchat_invite` handler like this and it works:

```
diff --git a/examples/muc.py b/examples/muc.py
index 5b5c764..e327fac 100755
--- a/examples/muc.py
+++ b/examples/muc.py
@@ -61,7 +61,10 @@ class MUCBot(sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP):
         # muc::room@server::got_online, or muc::room@server::got_offline.
         self.add_event_handler("muc::%s::got_online" % self.room,
                                self.muc_online)
-
+        self.add_event_handler("groupchat_invite", self.accept_invite)
+
+    def accept_invite(self, inv):
+       print("Invite from %s to %s" %(inv["from"], inv["to"]))

     def start(self, event):
         """
```

Comment: Ah, you are just mistyping hand*l*er there :)